# Is there a "deleter" in D?

Tags: class, properties, d, getter-setter

Is there a way to implement a *deleter* in D? I could not find any references to that. In the following example, I want to use the *deleter* to reset the value of `internal` back to its original state. If there is no such thing as a *deleter*, then what would be the preferred and idiomatic way to achieve the above mentioned requirement? (And if that is the case, I'm also interested in the design choice, on why such type of property function is not part of the language?)

```
class Class
{
    private uint internal = 0;

    @property uint value()
    {
        return this.internal;
    }

    @property uint value(uint input)
    {
        return this.internal = input;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the conversation below: I gave a dummy example, which led us to think, that this mechanism I'm looking for can easily be achieved via a simple *setter* and the usage of the `.init` value of the attribute. However that is not the case. What if this property is basically just a convenient wrapper around several function calls? Like a couple of C function invocations that resets the semantically related states -- which is exactly the case of mine.

To clarify even further, we are talking about a similar mechanism that Python has, which is supporting *getter*, *setter* and *deleter*.

Comment: What the hell is a deleter? `void reset(){ internal = 0; }`?

Comment: Apparently Python has this concept. And that's pretty much it.

Comment: @weltensturm as **sigod** mentioned this above, for example Python has this concept. The name itself may not be the best choice, but it is indeed quite handy. After all, if you have a *setter* and a *getter* why won't you have a *deleter*? In the above case, I would call it *resetter* or something like that, just as **BioTronic** did in his answer.

Comment: So the point is basically to forward `delete(a.value);` to a special function that does `this.internal = this.internal.init;`, or whatever else should be done when you delete `a.value`?

Comment: @BioTronic exactly! but now, that you put it like that, it is just a special case of a *setter*, isn't it?

Comment: @BioTronic you confused me a bit -- it is not the same! I gave you a dummy example, which led us to a dummy solution. What if this property is basically a convenient wrapper around several functions? (Like a tons of C function calls that resets the semantically related state resets -- which is exactly the case of mine)

Comment: They are somewhat the same, but not quite. D has no special concept for this special setter. If you really want to, you can have `@property uint value(typeof(null) input) { /* Cleanup(); */ }` and do special cleanup in that function. `a.value = null;` would then call this special overload. I've never seen that used, so I wouldn't exactly call it idiomatic.

Comment: if you don't mind @BioTronic I would appreciate if you would add this comment of yours to your answer, because I think it is somewhat more useful than the one you already wrote -- well, at least for me :)

Comment: Done. As I explain there, a more idiomatic way would probably be a `clearValue()` function.

Comment: seriously this question makes no sense.

Comment: @hasen did you read the comments as well?

Comment: @hasen I updated the question as well, hope it is worthy of the `-1` removal now!

Comment: Sorry, still makes no sense to me. I've worked in python a lot and I've never heard of a deleter before. Your question does not clarify what a deleter is at all.

Comment: If by deleter in python you mean what gets executed upon running `del object.property` then that makes absolutely no sense in D. Structs and classes in D are not hash tables. You don't add and remove properties from structs or objects willy-nilly.

Comment: @hasen I think you misunderstood how a *deleter* is working in Python! Yes, basically everything is a hash table, modules, classes, what not, but when you perform `del obj.prop` and `prop` is an actual `property` (the built-in type), the `.deleter` method will be called on the `property` object, which ofc calling the composed function you decorated. The fact that you never used it, does not mean it is unnecessary, but I admit, it is not used as often as the other two. Anyways, all of these property methods are used as mechanisms, as abstractions, not as single operations in most cases!

Comment: Still, the delete statement on properties makes no sense in D. You can always just write a method to reset whatever you want. No need to look for an idiomatic or "approved" way of doing it. Actually if your "property" is doing a lot of function calls, does it even make sense to pretend it's a property? You can keep it as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I had never heard of a deleter before, I initially answered a somewhat different question than what was asked. D does not have anything like Python's deleters, and the below suggestion could not be called idiomatic, but it does essentially the same thing and looks somewhat similar.

Note that this will lead to non-intuitive behavior for nullable types - `a.value = null;` will call the special deleter function, while `a.value = cast(Foo*)null;` will call the regular setter. So you probably shouldn't do this at all.

A more idiomatic way would be to either have a separate `clearValue()` function or do automatic cleanup when the value is set to its 'deleted' value (be that null, 0 or whatever).

```
class Class
{
    private uint internal = 0;

    @property uint value()
    {
        return this.internal;
    }

    @property uint value(uint input)
    {
        return this.internal = input;
    }

    // deleter
    @property uint value(typeof(null) input)
    {
        DoSpecialCleanup();
        return this.internal = internal.init;
    }
}

unittest
{
    auto c = new Class();
    c.value = 13;
    assert(c.value == 13);
    c.value = null; // Calling deleter here.
    assert(c.value == 0);
}
```

In my initial (mis)understanding of the question, I took it to mean a reset of all fields to their initial values. That could be done with the following code:

```
import std.traits;

void reset(T)(auto ref T t) if (is(T == Unqual!T)) {
    static if (is(T == class)) {
        auto data = T.classinfo.initializer[0..$];

        foreach (e; FieldNameTuple!T) {
            alias FieldType = typeof(__traits(getMember, T, e));
            enum offset = __traits(getMember, T, e).offsetof;

            static if (is(FieldType == Unqual!FieldType)) {
                __traits(getMember, t, e) = *cast(FieldType*)data[offset..$];
            }
        }
    } else static if (!is(typeof(t = T.init))) {
        foreach (e; FieldNameTuple!T) {
            alias FieldType = typeof(__traits(getMember, T, e));

            static if (is(FieldType == Unqual!FieldType)) {
                __traits(getMember, t, e) = __traits(getMember, T.init, e);
            }
        }
    } else {
        t = T.init;
    }
}

class Bar {
    align(16):
    int n = 3;
    const int n2 = 19;
}

struct Baz {
    align(16):
    int n = 3;
    const int n2 = 19;
}

unittest {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.n = 14;
    reset(b);
    assert(b.n == 3);

    Baz b2;
    b2.n = 14;
    reset(b2);
    assert(b2.n == 3);
}
```

Comment: What if null is a valid value for the property?

Comment: Then you have a problem. :p Actually, it's even worse than what you might at first imagine - `a.value = null;` will behave differently from `a.value = cast(Foo*)null;`. So yeah, I guess I should clarify that you simply shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 2):

In short - *no*, there is no *deleter* (a la Python) in D. The deleter in Python exists mostly because of Python's *dynamic nature*.

Python3 example:

```
class MyType():
    """Demonstrates the use of the *deleter* ...
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._someval = None

    @property
    def someval(self):
        return self._someval

    @someval.setter
    def someval(self, value):
        self._someval = value

    @someval.deleter
    def someval(self):
        print('someval about to be deleted')
        del self._someval


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyType()
    obj.someval = 42
    print(obj.someval)
    del obj.someval # we trigger the deleter here
    print(obj.someval) # AttributeError thrown...
```

In this simple example above it is obvious that the member "variable" 'someval' is dynamically created (in Python these are all just keys in a dictionary...) and as such can easily be unset/destroyed with the *del* Python keyword.

In D this is not possible for obvious reason - in D you cannot dynamically unset an attribute! - All members exist for as long as the object exists. D's property mechanism (very simple, yet effective) does not provide the deleter - only getter and setter are available, and it all makes sense...

Comment: To nitpick, you could have the property be backed by a key in a hashtable (would probably be a stupid thing to do, but possible) and you can then delete that key. But there's no `delete object.field` statement

Comment: Although this one is a decent example, the fact that Python has `deleter` has nothing to do with its *dynamic nature*!

Comment: If Python was not a dynamic language, deleter would not be there. Simple as that...

Comment: @hasen - that would be one way to emulate the Python's deleter behaviour, yep.

Comment: @DejanLekic what makes you say that? *deleter* is just a mechanism, nothing less, nothing more. It has syntactic-sugar reasons (operator overloading) and therefore higher level of abstraction of cleanup methods, but that's it. You could simulate the same thing in D (see the above answer) or even in C, which means, it has nothing to do with its *dynamic nature* -- it has things to do with doing things at run time instead of compile time -- wether it is a good idea to do so in these languages depends on the actual situation.

Comment: As you said, you can only *simulate* what del does in D and C! Why? - Because none of them allow you to DYNAMICALLY remove an attribute from an object! Imagine you have a `struct S { int a; int b; int c }`, you create a value of this type with `S foo = { 1, 2, 3 };` and then (thank God C/D do not allow it) you execute `del foo.b` !?!? - Once you do this, your type is DIFFERENT (it contains only two integers).